# Visual Studio 2019 View.SynchroniseClassView not working

Tags: visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise, View.SynchroniseClassView is not working. I have tried adding the button to menu, map keys to View.SynchroniseClassView , but the button remains greyed out.

Is there any known issues with View.SynchroniseClassView ? The worse case scenario is trying to find a way to copy the fully qualified method/property name and search in the class view manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Visual Studio Version 16.7.1 The issue seems fixed and the position in the tree view of the class view matches the code when invoking the synchronise class view key shortcut or menu entry in the "View > Syncronize Class View"